# no cierra un elemento de la pagina web

Tags: html, web, bootstrap-4

he insertado los botones de `Play Store` y no me deja cerrar el elemento, por lo tanto pulse donde pulse en la web me lleva al link de `Play Store`. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```html
<!-- Welcome-area-start -->
<div class="welcome-area home-2" style="background-image: url(img/bg-img/bg-img2.png)" id="home">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-2 col-sm-7">
        <div class="welcome-content mt-sm-100">
          <h3 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Gestiona tu tiempo <br>Make it easy!</h3>

          <li class="nav-item pl-4">
            <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=XXXX" </a>
              <img src="img/playstore.png" alt="">
              <img src="img/applestore.png" alt="">
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="welcome-thumb home-3" style="margin-top: 110px">
          <img src="img/bg-img/smartmockups_kconkpot.png" alt="XXX app">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Welcome-area-end -->
```

Comment: Te falta cerrar el `a`, es decir, tenes que poner `<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=XXXX"></a>`. A parte de eso, los `li` deben ir dentro de un `ul`

Comment: vale, me faltaba > justo antes de cerrar a. pero si hago eso se me descoloca toda la imagen... ¿cómo puedo dejarlo igual?

Comment: Es imposible para mi saber que es lo que estas viendo... pero se me ocurre que la `img` del `playstore.png` debería estar dentro del `a`, algo así: `<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=XXXX"><img src="img/playstore.png" alt=""></a>`. Intenta crear un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: todo se me mueve... voy a pedir ayuda da un amigo porque sin ver la web es complicado. Gracias de todos modos!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

te dejo el código correcto y algunas observaciones

las etiquetas que no van con otra etiqueta de cierre deben terminar en /> pues estas se autocierran, las etiquetas li van dentro de un ul, tenias un cierre de más en un div.

```
<!-- Welcome-area-start -->
<div class="welcome-area home-2" style="background-image: url(img/bg-img/bg-img2.png)" id="home">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-2 col-sm-7">
        <div class="welcome-content mt-sm-100">
          <h3 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Gestiona tu tiempo <br>Make it easy!</h3>
            <ul>
          <li class="nav-item pl-4">
            <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=XXXX"> 
              <img src="img/playstore.png" alt="" />
              <img src="img/applestore.png" alt="" />
                </a>
          </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="welcome-thumb home-3" style="margin-top: 110px"/>
          <img src="img/bg-img/smartmockups_kconkpot.png" alt="XXX app" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Welcome-area-end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Te está faltando cerrar ti etiqueta `a` con `>`

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=XXXX" </a>

<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=XXXX"> </a>
```

Y veo que tienes problema para acomodar la imagen de playstore.

Utilizar la clase `navbar-brand` te podría ayudar. Asumiendo que estas usando bootstrap.

```html
<li class="nav-item  pl-4">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=XXXX">
        <img src="img/playstore.png" alt="" />
        <img src="img/applestore.png" alt=""/>
    </a>
</li>
```

Yo tengo un código como el siguiente

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<li class="nav-link">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.laravel.com">
    <i class="fab fa-laravel">Laravel</i>
  </a>
</li>
```